# Proof of a lemma in a paper on Variational Methods

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

The following is a Lemma on a paper I am reading (Existence of Solutions to a Singular Elliptic Equation - M. Montenegro - 2011). I am having some trouble with the conclusion of the proof and would be the most glad for any help.

First, a few definitions. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$, $0 < q < p < 1$ and $0 < \beta < 1$ and define
$$
g_\varepsilon(u) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{u^q}{(u + \varepsilon)^{q + \beta}}, \quad u \geq 0 \\
0, \quad u < 0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
G_\varepsilon(u) = \int_0^ug_\varepsilon(s) \ ds \geq 0
$$
and $I_\varepsilon: H_0^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
I_\varepsilon(u) = \frac 12 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \ dx + \int_\Omega G_\varepsilon(u) \ dx - \frac{\lambda}{p + 1} \int_\Omega(u^+)^{p + 1}
$$

> **Lemma:** Given $\lambda > 0$, there exist $a_2, b_2 > 0$ and $0 < \rho < 1$ such that for every $0 < \varepsilon < 1$
> $$
> I_\varepsilon(u) \geq a_2 > 0 \quad \forall u \text{ such that } \|u\|_{H_0^1} = \rho,
> $$
> the functional $I_\varepsilon$ is coercive and bounded from below by $-b_2$.

> *Proof:*[As in the paper] From the definition of $g_\varepsilon$, we have that
> $$
> g_\varepsilon (t) \geq \frac{t^q}{(t + 1)^{q + \beta}}
> $$
> for every $t \geq 0$. Since $q < p$ we may find $\delta(\lambda)$ such that
> $$
> g_\varepsilon(t) \geq \lambda t^p \quad \forall 0 \leq t \leq \delta.
> $$
> (for a proof, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744197/if0-q-p-1and-lambda-0-there-is-delta-lambda-s-t-fractq)) Taking $\rho$ sufficiently small, we obtain $I_\varepsilon(u) \geq a_2 := \rho^2/4$ for every $u$ such that $\|u\|_{H_0^1} = \rho$. We also obtain that
> $$
> I_\varepsilon(u) \geq \frac12 \|u\|_{H_0^1}^2 - C\|u\|_{H_0^1}^p,
> $$
> from which the boundedness and coercivity follow.

My questions:

1. How can we conclude that $I_\varepsilon(u) \geq \rho^2/4$ for all $\|u\|_{H_0^1} = \rho$? I have no clue on that.
2. Does the last inequality follow because $\|u^+\|_p^p \leq \|u\|_p^p \leq \|u\|_{H_0^1}^p$?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to both questions in this more detailed paper by the same author together with Elves Silva: [Two solutions for a singular elliptic equation by variational methods](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_2012_5_11_1_143_0.pdf)